# jQuery select2 with remote data and asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jsonp, generic-handler

I am using select2 library for replacing select boxes. I rearranged example 7 that you can find on [Select2 library](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) page (scroll down with id 
`$("#e7").select2` etc...). I made my own generic handler that return serialized json data:

GetData.asxh view :
    public class GetData : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

```
    public class RecipesList
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public List<TopRecipeTable> recipes { get; set; }

        public RecipesList() { }

        public RecipesList(int total, List<TopRecipeTable> recipes)
        {
            this.total = total;
            this.recipes = recipes;
        }
    }

    private string GenerateJsonSerializedObject(int languageId, string orderBy)
    {            
        RecipesList recipeList = new RecipesList(15, DBDataBase.GetTopRecipesByNumberOfRecipes(languageId, 15));
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(recipeList);
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int languageId;            
        bool languageParsed = int.TryParse(context.Request["languageId"], out languageId);
        string orderBy = (string)context.Request["orderBy"];

        if (languageParsed && orderBy != string.Empty)
        {enter code here
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            var jsonValue = GenerateJsonSerializedObject(languageId, orderBy);
            context.Response.Write(jsonValue);
        }
    }
```

This generic handler returns the right format of json (I checked it with [this URL](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) ). My result (json) is also the same as the one in example on above mentioned page. But after this jquery doesn`t fire anymore.

My script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#e8").select2({
            placeholder: "Search for a recipe",
            //minimumInputLength: 1,
            ajax: {                               
                url: "/Handlers/GetData.ashx",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        languageId: 1,
                        orderBy: "TA"
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    alert(data.total);
                    var more = (page * 10) < data.total; // whether or not there are more results available

                    // notice we return the value of more so Select2 knows if more results can be loaded
                    return { results: data.recipes, more: more };
                }
            },
            formatResult: movieFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            formatSelection: movieFormatSelection, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
            escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
        });
    });
```

I tried to write the same `alert(data.total)` in the original example and it worked but not in my version. So I have the right json format, the jquery calls my generic handler and also recieved parameters languageId ... and also return the right json format but than nothing. I don't know if I am missing something here, because I am sure that this thing could also work with a generic handler as well. I hope I gave enough information about my problem.

```
I can also add my result in jquery .ajax error handler : 
xhr.status = 200
ajaxOptions = parsererror
horwnError = SyntaxError : invalid label
If this is any helpful information
```

Comment: You are serializing JavaScript, which gets you a json response. Yet in the ajax call you have specified dataType of jsonp. Change it to json and it should work, unless you have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, so pretty sure you have a solution by now...but:

Remove all of these functions:

formatResult: movieFormatResult
formatSelection: movieFormatSelection
dropdownCssClass: ...
escapeMarkup:....

You did not provide those functions to format your data did you?  All of those are only needed if you are making a custom drop down of items.

You are returning data.recipes - that needs to be an array of {Text:"", Id:""} or you need to build it from what you return right there.

First, get it working with just a very basic list with very basic data...then go from there.

Additionally, when you get that working try using WebApi or ServiceStack to handle your data instead of an IHttpHandler.